# MatDialog: use scroll strategy within the MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS provider?

Tags: angular, mat-dialog

I have a global config for the Angular Material dialog defined in app.module in providers as such:

```js
providers: [
  //...
  {
    provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: {
      hasBackdrop: true,
      backdropClass: 'modal-backdrop',
      closeOnNavigation: true,
    },
  },
]
```

I would like to define a scrollStrategy as well, I tried in various ways, either adding under `useValue` the following:

```js
scrollStrategy: BlockScrollStrategy, // either this or the next line
scrollStrategy: () => BlockScrollStrategy,
```

or by adding another extra provider:

```js
{
  provide: MAT_DIALOG_SCROLL_STRATEGY,
  useFactory: (scrollStrategyOptions: ScrollStrategyOptions) =>
    scrollStrategyOptions.block(),
  deps: [ScrollStrategyOptions],
},
```

In both cases I get errors:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: this._scrollStrategy is not a function
    at MatDialog._getOverlayConfig (dialog.js:679:1)
    at MatDialog._createOverlay (dialog.js:668:1)
```

I'm not exactly sure how the scrollStrategy is supposed to be used alongside `MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS`

Answer (score 3):

Provide on which you want the strategy to be applied and call it via factory. I am not sure if you want to apply the strategy to the overlay itself or some specific element in the overlay but this solution is for the latter. `MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE` for example. `MAT_DIALOG_SCROLL_STRATEGY` would be for the overlay dialogue itself but seems you were on the right track.

```js
import { BlockScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/scroll';

export function scrollFactory(overlay: Overlay): () => BlockScrollStrategy {
  return () => overlay.scrollStrategies.block();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    OverlayModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExample, DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  declarations: [DialogOverviewExample, DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  bootstrap: [DialogOverviewExample],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_SCROLL_STRATEGY,
      useFactory: scrollFactory,
      deps: [Overlay],
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

An example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-dialog-scroll-h9zwel?file=main.ts

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The only thing I had to change in my code was use `[Overlay]` for deps instead of `[ScrollStrategyOptions]` and adapt the factory function code to target one level higher, starting from overlay. Still it would be nice to provide it under `MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` with the rest of the options, not sure if it is possible though.